# Save a webpage in xaml/ C# to ApplicationData, universal app

Tags: c#, xaml, webview

I am learning C# and xaml, now when isolated storage isn't in windows universal, how can I save a page from the internet and compare it with a previously downloaded page and than view it in the webview?
Here is my attempt:
C# code:

```
public sealed partial class OdpadloPage : Page
{

    public OdpadloPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().
                  SetDesiredBoundsMode(ApplicationViewBoundsMode.UseVisible);
    }
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
    }

}
```

My xaml code:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <EntranceThemeTransition/>
        </TransitionCollection>
    </Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
    <WebView Margin="10,0,10,10" Source="http://www.gyarab.cz/suplovani/suplov.htm"/>

</Grid>
```

Comment: This is *not* an attempt. None of that code has the intention of solving the problem. Here's [an article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/6d1860/how-to-implement-local-storage-in-universal-windows-apps/) that *might* help.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned , IsolatedStorageSettings is not supported at Windows Universal.Instead , you must use ApplicationDataContainer.

What you have to do is simply call InvokeScriptAsync method of your webview and get the current source code of the page (you can use one-lined javascript code) and save it to the local settings by using ApplicationDataContainer.

Sorry that I'm not able to provide you some code examples atm.